# 500 Server Error using cgitb - shared hosting

Tags: python

I tried to write a simple Python script but it gave me this error when testing it in the browser.

```
500 Server Error
```

A misconfiguration on the server caused a hiccup. I checked the server logs, fixed the problem, then tried again.

URL: http://example.com/cgi-bin/hello.py
Not executable: [/home1/example/public_html/cgi-bin/hello.py]

`hello.py` content is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

# enable debugging
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8"
print

print "Hello World!"
```

I'm on shared hosting, according to my web hosting provider. The error is in my code.

Comment: Looks like a permissions problem.. does the web server user have permission to execute the file?

Comment: But the permission is already 755

Comment: is selinux in use on the server?

Comment: Yes Linux. My hello.py is located at public_html/cgi-bin/hello.py and I have .htaccess file at public_html/.htaccess. When i tried to removed .htaccess I got this code running. The content of the .htaccess is a redirection code.

Comment: Since the error is coming from the server: What server are you using? And what version? And is this really plain CGI, or some other web app interface? (If so, _why_ is it plain CGI? If I time-traveled to 1998, how am I using StackOverflow…?) And can you post the actual log lines?

Comment: Also, are you sure there is a Python interpreter at `/usr/bin/python`? It's pretty much guaranteed that `#!/usr/bin/env python` will work on any modern *nix, but not necessarily `#!/usr/bin/python`.

Comment: Finally, are you doing any server configuration yourself, or is that all left up to the hosting provider? (I had an insanely silly error recently on a NAS where the out-of-the-box Apache config told it to run anything with the extensions `.pl`, `.p`, or `.py` by ignoring the shebang and running it with a Perl interpreter, which needless to say didn't make Python scripts very happy…)

Comment: I got this running already when I removed my .htaccess file. I think the source of the problem is my .htaccess which is a redirection to another domain. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a permissions problem. The only other suggestion I have is to check what version of Python is installed on the server. If it is 3.3 then the print statements should be changed to `print()` with the brackets.

Comment: Thanks @RogueThinking but I got this running already when I removed my .htaccess file outside of the cgi-bin directory.